# Complexity of computing the homology of a finite topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, algorithms, homology-cohomology, computational-complexity

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Given a finite topological space $X$ with $|X|=n$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$, decide if $H_k(X,\mathbb{F})=0$.

Where $\mathbb{F}$ denotes some field and one can also assume that $X$ is $T_0$ and reduced (a minimal finite $T_0$ topological space). In this case, the input finite topological space can be represented by a poset. I am interested if this decision problem is NP-hard. The problem can be viewed as a special case of to the homology problem for clique complexes of graphs which is known to be NP-hard in general. I am thinking about this problem for a while now but i got stuck. I would be very thankful for any suggestions.

If you are interested in this problem feel free to write me a private message.

Comment: Is this problem equivalent to asking when the homology of a finite cw complex vanishes? I think that it can be a hard problem in general.

Comment: You can construct the order complex of a finite space which is a finite simplicial complex that is weakly homotopy equivalent to the finite space. Unfortunately the size of the order complex is exponential in the size of the finite space so you don't get a polynomial reduction. I also conjecture that it is a hard problem.